# problem in query_vars parameters

Tags: wp-query, parameter

I've a problem. I've tried a lot of things but I could not find a solution.
I use query_vars parameters in [this page](http://www.oyunkayit.com/oyunara?ara=s4&kategori=1) and there isn't any problem. But i don't use different parameters or the same parameters in different custom page (../videolar). Parameter value is always empty.
Parameters used once ?
Function.php :

```
function parameter($qvars){ 
     $qvars[] = 'kategori';
     $qvars[] = 'ara';
     $qvars[] = 'numara';
     $qvars[] = 'tur';
     return $qvars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'parameter');
```

videolar.php (../videolar?tur=test) :

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->query_vars['tur'] // empty
```

Comment: Could you rephrase: "But i don't use different parameters or the same parameters in different custom page (../videolar)."  I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.

Re-save your permalink settings after you add the parameter. Or change the file permissions of .htaccess to 777.

Comment: Where do you re-save your permalink settings?

Comment: You just go to Settings > Permalinks. When you visit that page WordPress automatically refreshes all permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can understand, you are looking to `echo` out the value of a query variable.  The WordPress function for getting a query variable is [`get_query_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).

So in your `videolar.php` template you would add:

```
echo get_query_var('tur');
```

Comment: i've tried this, value is still empty.

Comment: Hmm.... well then I would disable all your plugins and maybe switch to the default theme to try to isolate the problem.  What you are doing looks right to me. Sorry I can't be more helpful!